# Ubuntu Terminal shows ASCII codes character

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image: Terminal ubuntu 20.04]

I recently update to 20.04 ubuntu. But suddenly terminal cannot display words correctly. Here is what it looks like now. Any idea?

Comment: Could you please post the content of `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` and the font that your terminal uses?

Comment: those are not weird characters ... they are characters that show ASCII codes ... http://www.asciitable.com/mobile/

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-20-04-release-features/ reminds us 20.04 is scheduled for release on 4/23, 20 days from now. Issues with pre-release software are normal. If you download tomorrow's daily, install that, and the problem persists, you may report it following this procedure: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: @luca The file is totally blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose another font for your terminal and the problem will be gone.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.